# Can't use VueJS attribute prefixes in JSF facelets

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I put something like this in my JSF facelets:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <f:view>
        <h:head></h:head>
        <h:body>
            <todo-item
                v-for="item in groceryList"
                v-bind:todo="item"
                v-bind:key="item.id">
            </todo-item>
            ...
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

And get the error:

```
The prefix "v-bind" for attribute "v-bind:todo" associated with an element type "todo-item" is not bound.
```

I understand what the problem is. The namespace is not defined on the HTML element. But how could I? I tried using `xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"`, `p:v-bind:todo` and `p:v-bind:key`, but that was a long shot and didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up simply doing like this:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:v-bind="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <f:view>
        <h:head></h:head>
        <h:body>
            <todo-item
                v-for="item in groceryList"
                v-bind:todo="item"
                v-bind:key="item.id">
            </todo-item>
            ...
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Comment: sure the v-bind is in the resulting html then?

Answer (score 0):

Marriage between VUE and JSF2 is hellish. I want to use the facelets templates and model binding of JSF2 and the front-end magic of VUE

Ended up with statements like:

```
xmlns:v-on="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:v-bind="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

binding JSF to backing bean and binding to vue for front end validation

```
<h:inputText a:placeholder="eMail" maxlength="17" value="#{LoginBean.email}" a:v-model="email"/>
```

binding css classes and conditional rendering using vue

```
<div class="button" v-bind:class="{ disabled: !login_enabled }">
    <span v-if="login_enabled">
        <h:commandLink action="#{LoginBean.submit}">
            <span class="button-title">Submit</span>
            <f:ajax execute="@form"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </span>
    <span v-if="!login_enabled" class="button-title">Submit</span>
</div>
```

Honestly, not sure this is the right path for my project. For now, it works, will see later.

Comment: How is this different than the other answer?

Comment: just different example, so ppl can see more

Comment: In my humble opinion it is the same